# Self referential embedded documents using Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Say I have a mongoid model called Foo that embeds many Bar.

```
class Foo
    ...
    embeds_many :bar
    ...
end

class Bar
    ...
    embedded_in :foo
    ...
end
```

I would like to create a relationship where Bar links to it's self. The relationship will always concern two documents that are embedded in the same Foo document. I don't seem to be able to do this with out getting nil back when calling the relationship. I have tried

```
belongs_to :discovered_by, :class_name => 'Bar'
```

and also

```
has_one :discovered_by, :class_name => 'Bar'
```

While the discovered_by id is set in the Bar document and pointing to the other Bar document when I try and do the following I get nil (assuming that the first Bar of the first Foo has the discovered_by_id set)

```
Foo.first.bars.first.discovered_by
```

This will always return nil despite the doucment having the id set. Any idea as to why this is happening? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [cannot have references to embedded models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890633/how-to-reference-an-embedded-document-in-mongoid) - even when they're both embedded in the same document. If you correctly configure the relationship

```
belongs_to :discovered_by, :class_name => 'Bar', inverse_of: :discovered
has_one :discovered, :class_name => 'Bar', inverse_of: :discovered_by
```

Mongoid will raise a `Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations` exception. Maybe you could reconsider if embedding these objects is still the best choice. A workaround is storing only the id and query the parent object:

```
class Bar
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :foo
    field :discovered_by_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId

    def discovered_by
      foo.bars.find(discovered_by_id) if discovered_by_id
    end

    def discovered_by=(bar)
      self.discovered_by_id = bar.id
    end
end
```

Comment: I think I will have to store the id as you have suggested in your work around solution. Not ideal but it servers my purpose. That having been said your comment about reconsidering embedded documents is interesting. Is it against the "mongo way" of doing things to think of two documents that are embedded in the same parent document as related? I suppose that would be consistent with Mongoid's implementation.

Comment: Yes, generally it's a bad idea to have references to embedded documents. Partially from a technical point of view (the object using the relation has to know the parent's object for each layer of embedded models) and a design point of view (embedded objects should only be accessed through their parent). However, your example is somewhat of an edge case: you definitely know the parent object of the record you're referring to (`foo`). I'd probably go with the workaround  - the only drawback is that you cannot use the standard `belongs_to` and `has_one` helpers.